# Append to file in a consistent way

Tags: c#, .net-core, filesystems

I'm searching for the correct technique, if exists, to append to a file a chunk of data "all or nothing" in the sense I want my application to be resilient to crashes of the app itself, or power down, by leaving the file in a consistent state. I'm using NET core and the application is currently multi platform enabled, so I would prefer a cross platform idea.

Comment: Its the file - text or bytes?

Comment: @RobertPerry does it make difference? Anyway I think it will be text, is a sort of journal file.

Comment: If the file is not big and you don't care about thread safety, then the simplest solution would be to create a copy of the file before you start append. Once completed replace the original file. I came across this idea in [TransactionalFileMgr](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=transactionalfilemgr) (dig in their source) and also in [Oren's blog](https://ayende.com/blog/3456/code-critique-transactional-file)